# La funcion de indentificador va bien, pero al meterla en otra me dice que .split no existe, y lo mismo con .substring, el resto del codigo es correcto

Tags: javascript, split, substring

```js
window.onload=inicio;

function inicio(){
    document.querySelector("#gmail").onkeydown=tecladoGMAIL;
}  
function tecladoGMAIL(input){
    const tecla=input.key;
    if (tecla=="Enter"){
        agregarGMAIL();
    }
}
function agregarGMAIL(){
    const gmailEscrito=document.querySelector("#gmail").value.trim();
    let gmail=[];
    gmail.push(gmailEscrito);
    vaciarGMAIL();
    mostrarGMAIL(gmail);
    console.log(gmailEscrito)
    inicio();
}

function vaciarGMAIL(){
    document.querySelector("#gmail").value="";
    document.querySelector("#gmail").focus();
}
// hasta aqui todo bien
function identificador (gmail) {
    let valor
    let char = gmail.split('') // este split es el que no reconoce
    for (var i = 0; i<gmail.length; i++){
        if (char[i] == '@'){
            if (char[i+1]== '.'){
                valor = true
            };
        };
    };
    console.log(valor);
    if(valor){
        return (`Tu correo electronico si cumple con las condiciones`);
    }else if(!valor){
        return (`Tu correo electronico no cumple con las condiciones`);
    }
};
function mostrarGMAIL(gmail){
    let result = identificador(gmail)
    document.getElementById("mail").innerHTML=(result);
    console.log(`Resultado: ${result}`);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practicas</title>
    <script src="iva.js" defer></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div > 
            <p>Practicas JavaScript</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="gmail">
            <p>Condiciones Gmail</p>
            <label for="nombre">Escribe tu correo electronico para ver si cumple las condiciones:                   </label>
            <input id="gmail"type="text"autocomplete="off"autofocus placeholder="Escribe tu mail"/>
            <p id="mail">Condiciones:</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que agregar el método **`toString()`** para que el tipo de dato se convierta en **`string`** y hagas el **`split()`** sin problemas:

```
let char = gmail.toString().split('')
```

Ahora para verificar que caracteres tiene el arreglo que te vota el **`split()`**, yo usaría el método **`includes()`** para verificar si incluye dicho caracter en el arreglo:

```
for (var i = 0; i<gmail.length; i++){
  if (char.includes("@")){
    if (char.includes(".")){
      valor = true
    };
  };
};
```

Tu código final sería el siguiente:

```js
window.onload = inicio;

function inicio() {
  document.querySelector('#gmail').onkeydown = tecladoGMAIL;
}
function tecladoGMAIL(input) {
  const tecla = input.key;
  if (tecla == 'Enter') {
    agregarGMAIL();
  }
}
function agregarGMAIL() {
  const gmailEscrito = document.querySelector('#gmail').value.trim();
  let gmail = [];
  gmail.push(gmailEscrito);
  vaciarGMAIL();
  mostrarGMAIL(gmail);
  inicio();
}

function vaciarGMAIL() {
  document.querySelector('#gmail').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#gmail').focus();
}

function identificador(gmail) {
  let valor;
  let char = gmail.toString().split('');
  console.log(char);
  for (var i = 0; i < gmail.length; i++) {
    if (char.includes('@')) {
      if (char.includes('.')) {
        valor = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if (valor) {
    return `Tu correo electronico si cumple con las condiciones`;
  } else if (!valor) {
    return `Tu correo electronico no cumple con las condiciones`;
  }
}
function mostrarGMAIL(gmail) {
  let result = identificador(gmail);
  document.getElementById('mail').innerHTML = result;
  console.log(`Resultado: ${result}`);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <p>Practicas JavaScript</p>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="gmail">
    <p>Condiciones Gmail</p>
    <label for="nombre">Escribe tu correo electronico para ver si cumple las condiciones:</label>
    <input id="gmail" type="text" autocomplete="off" autofocus placeholder="Escribe tu mail"/>
    <p id="mail">Condiciones:</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

**Enlaces:**

- **[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**
- **[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)**
- **[Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)**